# how vulnerable is this JS line "document.cookie="xxx" to cross browser attacks?

Tags: javascript, cookies, browser

```
document.cookie="username=" + uid + ";" + "expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2023 12:00:00 GMT; path=/";
```

how to make this more secure, since this is visible in html ?

is this vulnerable to cross browser attacks ?

assuming I have to use JS.

Comment: It depends on where `uid` is coming from...so where is it coming from?

Answer (score 0):

This is safe since you don't store any personal information in the cookie. It would be impossible for an attacker to imporsonate the user from only this data.

Comment: it is not so much about the content of the cookie, my question is weather this data is accessible from known techniques (ie document.cookie in JS)?